# Add child + hittest?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest, tween, flappy-bird-clone

AS3 Flash -

Hey, I made a game like "Flappy Bird".

Can someone help me how to check "character" hitted a wall?

This game generate every 2.5 seconds two walls. (Wall and Wall2)

How to check that character hitted it?

```
function newWall():void
{
var Wall:wall = new wall();
addChildAt(Wall, 1);
Wall.x = -350 + (-80 - -350) * Math.random();
Wall.y = 805;
Wall.name = "Wall1_Object";
TweenLite.to(Wall, 10, {y:-50, ease:Linear.easeNone});

var Wall2:wall = new wall();
addChildAt(Wall2, 1);
Wall2.x = Wall.x + Wall.width + 125;
Wall2.y = 805;
Wall2.name = "Wall2_Object";
TweenLite.to(Wall2, 10, {y:-50, ease:Linear.easeNone});
}

function checkDead():void
{
if (character.hitTestObject(Wall) || character.hitTestObject(Wall2))
{
    trace("You dead!");
}
}

var newWallInterval:uint = setInterval(newWall,2500);
var checkDeadInterval:uint = setInterval(checkDead,500);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the last walls can't be hit any more when the new walls created,Try to define Wall and Wall2 outside the new newWall function.,or you need create an array to save the walls, and do a loop to check if the role hit the wall.